The probability of one of three people getting the most balls from ten containers ranging from 1 to 10
There are 10 different boxes on the table, each containing small balls with the number of small balls ranging from 1 to 10. Sarah, Wendy and Ricky are asked to choose one box at random with the condition that none of the three are allowed to choose the same box. If Sarah's chance of getting the most small balls is expressed in rational form $\left(\dfrac pq \right)$, then what is the value of $p+q$?
I was completely perplexed with :

...small balls ranging from $1$ to $10$...

How to solve this problem? I honestly have no idea as to what the question means. If I understood it correctly, it's either there are $10$ containers and each container has uncertain number of balls i.e. ranging from $1$ to $10$, so it could be $4$ or $6$ or $3$ for each, but never $0$ or $15$, for instance. OR they are just $10$ containers which from the first container it has $1$, the second has $2$, the third has $3$ and so on... either way I wasn't able to come up with something.
I tried using AI solver to answer this question and this is what It thinks about:

To determine the probability that Sarah gets the most number of small
balls, we need to consider the total number of possible outcomes and
the number of favorable outcomes where Sarah's box contains the most
balls. First. let's calculate the total number of possible outcomes,
since there are $10$ boxes and each person chooses a different box,
the total number of ways to choose the boxes is given by the
permutations of $10$ boxes taken $3$ at a time: $10 \times 9 \times 8$, which is $720$.
Next, we need to count the number of favorable outcomes where Sarah's
box contains the most balls. lf Sarah's box contains the most balls,
then the number of balls in Sarah's box must be one of the numbers
from $3$ to $10$ (since if it were $1$ or $2$, it would not be
possible for Sarah to have the most balls). For each choice of the
number of balls in Sarah's box, say $k$ (where $k$ ranges from $3$ to
$10$), the number of balls in Wendy's and Ricky's boxes must be less
than $k$. Therefore, there are $k-1$ choices for the number of balls
in Wendy's box and $k-2$ choices for the number of balls in Ricky's
box (since Wendy's and Ricky's boxes must contain different numbers of
balls and both must be less than $k$). The number of ways to assign
the balls to Wendy's and Ricky's boxes is:  $$(k-1)\times (k-2)$$
Since there are $10$ choices for the number of balls in Sarah's box,
the total number of favorable outcomes is: $$\sum_{k=3}^{10}(k-1)(k-2)$$,  Solving the sum will get $240$. Therefore, the
probability that Sarah gets the most number of smallballs is $\frac{240}{720}$ or $\frac 13$. Thus $p+q=4$

That's what the AI solver says. However I still don't get as to why abruptly there is a sigma notation there. What did it try to tell? Using what method? Also it seems unnatural to think Sarah should choose the box ranging from $3$ to $10$ to be maximum, as why not $4$ to $10$, or $9$ to $10$?
Using another AI it led me $\dfrac{1}{10}$. I'm not satisfied with these robots' answers, because they're not consistent. Help please. Thanks in advance.

I agree the phrasing is poor. I would read it as saying that one box contains $1$, another contains $2$ and so on.  In particular,  i wouldn't think that a tie was possible.

In general,  I wouldn't bother asking AI systems to solve math problems.  They tend to just make things up.

Should say: both interpretations make sense,  though they lead to different answers.  My reading makes the problem easy ( each player is equally likely to win). But the other isn't much harder.

As mentioned in the comments,  my reading of the problem would be that the boxes all contained different numbers of balls. In that case,  ties are not possible,  and since each player is equally likely to win the game, the probability is $\frac 13$.
The other natural reading would be that each box is independently equally likely to contain  $1,2,\cdots 10 $ balls. Ties would then be possible.  Now we'd have a second ambiguity, namely: are we requiring that S has a unique max or would a tie for the max count? Just guessing that ties would count,  we just sum over cases.  If S has $k$, the probability that the others each have $\leq k$ is $\frac {k^2}{100}$ so the probability that S is at least tied for the win is $$\sum_{k=1}^{10} \frac {k^2}{1000}=\frac {385}{1000}$$
The case where we demand S to have a unique max is similar.
